# Unable to install ttf-loader for React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react with typescript and I'm trying to use the font feature in react-pdf/renderer. I've successfully imported the font and registered it:

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Font } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import MyCustomFont from "../fonts/Calibri.ttf"

Font.register({
    family: "CalibriFamily",
    src: MyCustomFont
})
```

When I run the application I get this error:
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Note: I downloaded the Calibri.ttf file from here (https://freefontsfamily.com/calibri-font-free-download/)

I assume the issue is that I need to install the ttf-loader npm module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttf-loader). When I try to do that I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: micro-host@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.88.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^5.82.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
PS C:\Users\name\Code\react_typescript_electron\micro-host> npm i ttf-loader
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: micro-host@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.88.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^5.82.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from file-loader@1.1.11
npm ERR! node_modules/file-loader
npm ERR!   peer file-loader@"^1.1.6" from ttf-loader@1.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/ttf-loader
npm ERR!     ttf-loader@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I am new to node so can anyone explain how I can resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Webpack 5 but are attempting to use modules that only support Webpack 4.

In Webpack 5, we moved to [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) which are natively supported in Webpack. Judging by your use of file-loader, you probably want to use a [resource asset](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#resource-assets).

You should uninstall ttf-loader and file-loader and use the following webpack config template to setup `.tff` files to be interpreted as resources.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.ttf/,
       type: 'asset/resource'

     }
   ]
 },
};
```

Your JS code should then work without modification.